# Copying an HTML table (including data entered by user) using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have an empty table defined

```
<table align="center"  class="bordered"  border="6" id="tableb_copy"></table>
```

I have a table with INPUT elements defined

```
<table align="center"  class="bordered"  border="6" id="tableb">
    <tr>
       <td><input type="text" value="test"></td>
       <td>test1</td>
       <td>test1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I use the following code to copy the content of tableb to tableb_copy

```
$('#tableb_copy').html($('#tableb').html());
```

It copies the table structure, but if the user has entered some data into the INPUT cell, this is not copied. 
Is there any way of copying the contents as well?

Thanks

Comment: Your HTML seems invalid, opening tags again instead of closing tags.

Comment: What are the table contents? Are you talking about form fields where the fields get copied but not the values? Because in a general sense your code [works](http://jsfiddle.net/sUu2q/).

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/nCyFK/ ?

Comment: Thanks for comments... I have corrected the errors in the HTML and made my question clearer.  See the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nCyFK/1/ (thank you Sachin) - if you try changing the content of the left cell, then it will not get copied

Comment: +1 for the updated question. _Now_ you can get some meaningful help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try cloning the table first then move the clone to the new place.

```
<div id='here'></div>
```

And js

```
$('#here').html($('#tableb').clone().attr('id', 'tableb_copy'));
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/nCyFK/4/

Comment: Hi spokey, thank you... your code works well in the fiddle but not in my code for some reason... I will investigate!

Comment: In the previous fiddle some tags in your table were not closed. Try checking them again.

Comment: Note that you don't need to introduce a new container element (the div) if you do something like `$('#tableb_copy').empty().append($('#tableb').children().clone());` (http://jsfiddle.net/nCyFK/5/)

Comment: @nnnnnn, yes that may be a better solution, but instead of `.empty().append()` wouldn't `.html()` be easier?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work, excepted that your `<table>` is not HTML-valid.
The `<tr>` is a block tag, that you be ended with `</tr>` for instance.

http://jsfiddle.net/Bjmhw/1/

HTML:

```
<table align="center"  class="bordered"  border="6" id="tableb_copy"></table>
<table align="center"  class="bordered"  border="6" id="tableb">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$('#tableb_copy').html($('#tableb').html());
```

Comment: Thanks nnnnn for your answer... Sorry for the confusion -  I had made a mistake, simplifying my question so much that I left out the INPUT elements.